# Angular 6 router outlet display issue

Tags: angular6

I am having an issue displaying a router outlet correctly. On page load when a route is not loaded the first column in my row div is cutoff. The two screenshots summarize the issue, the first screenshot is the scenario with the error and the second screenshot is the scenario that works as desired where the router loads an item from the list.

**Snapshot of the error:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYQNF.jpg

I have also tried loading a default component on the empty route. However this loads the component but the app-wi-list on the left side is still cutoff. It seems that a WiDetailComponent must be loaded for the list to display in full size. Is there a way to load a component other than WiDetailComponent initially and still have the list display full size on the left side?

**Here is my html code:**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <app-wi-list></app-wi-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And the relevant routes:**

```
{path: 'work', component: WorkItemComponent, children: [
    {path: ':id', component: WiDetailComponent}
  ]},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using two outlets like this? The default will be for the list component, and the other with a name maybe "detailbar" for the detail component:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <router-outlet name="detailbar"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the routes should be this way, the outlet name for the detail component is "detailbar":

```
{
path: '', component: ListWorkItemComponent, children: [
  { path: 'detail1', component: WiDetailComponent, outlet: "detailbar" }
]},
```